# Memory Leak in iOS application - ARC

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, sdk, instruments

I have a hard time figuring out, where my app is leaking. I have tested it with the "Instruments" profiling application by allocations, with heapshots. This is what I got:

[image]

As you can see, the allocations is increasing. It increases every time I transitions between two views, with an fade effect.  In which of the following heapshots should I look in, in order to find the leak and what kind of objects should I look after, when I go through the heapshot/heapshots?

Thank you for the help in advance :).

Comment: See the stacktrace to know where you allocate that stuff.

Comment: It's ARC :).... I will try that. Is it right understod that the bytes allocated should be 0 bytes after the different heapshots? :) Thank you :).

Comment: Are you testing your code on an simulator or on a device? Because from my experience the results of the instruments regarding the memory leaks are not precise/accurate, but on a real device the results are correct.

Comment: I am testing on my device :) But is it correctly understod that the objects should be released (by the compiler, ARC) when I transition to a new view? Thank you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ARC can only deallocate the memory if you are not holding any references to it anymore. Since the leaks instrument doesn't indicate any "real" leaks (in the sense of memory that you don't have access to anymore), you are probably seeing a case of abandoned memory. You are still holding references to objects which you don't need anymore, so they don't get deallocated.

It doesn't really matter which snapshot you inspect after the baseline. The list of objects in a snapshot can be somewhat overwhelming though... but often it helps to filter it down to your own classes. You can do this by typing your class prefix into the search field in the upper right. If none of your classes show up in the snapshot, you can at least look for classes which you directly use.

Also make sure to enable the "Record reference counts" option in the inspector pane of the allocations instrument. When you have this enabled you can click on the little right-arrow next to the objects listed in a snapshot (not the class name, but the object represented by its memory address) and see a complete history of this object. This makes it easier to see who is holding references to it.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Build your code with the 'Analyze' option; track down and eliminate every issue.

Comment: I have tried that, but I do not get any "errors". Thank you for your answer:)